# httpd: multiple IP addresses, go to the same location

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, networking, centos, httpd

I've been looking into this for about 30 minutes now and don't really know of any easy way around this.  What I'm wanting to do is allow Apache to listen on all interfaces (this should already be configured since I have `Listen 80` defined in `httpd.conf`) and then no matter what IP is requested, to have any request go to `/var/www/html/`.

The only way that I know of would configure IP-based virtual hosts.  Is there another way that I'm just overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior in Apache - you shouldn't have to configure it.  If you set `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` and don't configure any virtual hosts, this is what will happen.

So, maybe you have some virtual hosts defined that are interfering with this behavior?

Comment: Correct and my overlook.  I couldn't reach the page because it was non-routable from my workstation, but only from the network other clients were on.  The primary IP that I was using was able to route, so that's why I could view it, but the secondary IP was the VLAN-specific IP that would only route within that VLAN, so I had to test it on a server in that VLAN.  Thanks for confirming though.